# How to dynamically write HTML based on a asp:Repeater value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an asp:Repeater control in my .aspx page that looks similar to:

```
<ol>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>                   
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ol>
```

Note: In the code-behind I'm am binding a generic list of data to the Repeater1 control

I'm am struggling with trying to find out how I can trap for values of the Container.DataItem and, then, depending on the value, change the style attribute of the [li style="myStyle"] tag.

I'm looking for an inline solution such that the pseudo-code would look something like this:

```
<ol>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <% if(Container.DataItem == "some value")
            {
            <li style="style1">                   
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </li>
            }
            else
            {
             <li style="style2">                   
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </li>
            }
            %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ol>
```

Is there an inline way of accomplishing the example psuedo-code above? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
<ol>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li style="<%# (string) Container.DataItem == "some value" ? "style1" : "style2" %>">                   
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ol>
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <%# string value = Container.DataItem as string; %>
            <li class="<%=value == "some value" ? "style1" : "style2" %>">
                <%=value %>
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ol>
```

Comment: Apparently, there are syntactical errors with your solution (i.e. I copy/pasted your sample and got an error). However, you've pointed me in the right direction - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write exactly that.

However, you should cast `Container.DataItem` to a string. Otherwise, you'll get a reference comparison.
If you aren't binding to a list of strings, you can cast `Container.DataItem` to whatever type it actually is and do things with it.